# IMPORT FONTS to Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, fonts, google-api, google-docs, google-fonts

Google Docs has no built in way to add custom fonts because it is cloud-based.

There is the *more fonts* button and the *extensis Fonts* add-on, but both only contain *Google Fonts*.

I have fonts that I would like to use for Google Docs, some of which come from *MyFonts.com* and others from *Adobe Fonts*.

**Does anyone know if there is a way use Google's scripting language to import desktop fonts?**

For instance, could I retrieve the files from an external location using URLfetchApp?

*Update:* I have not worked on this in a while but am still experiencing the same problems.

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, can you provide the sample Google Document including the sample text using the font you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike , I want to use fonts such as Baskerville MT, Baskerville BT, Sabon, and Serlio. There is, however, no specific text that I want to write in that font. I have been testing things using a few paragraphs of lorem ipsum.

Comment: The code I have been using is:

`var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();`
`  var body = doc.getBody();`
`  var data = {`
`    'contentType': 'font/otf',`
`  };`
`  var font = UrlFetchApp.fetch("URLToSerlioStd.otf", data);`
`  var fontFamily = font.getContentText();`
`  font`
`  var style = {};`
 ` style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = "Serlio Std";`

 ` body.setAttributes(style);`